# How do I edit Reitit routes in Reagent?

Tags: clojurescript, reagent, reitit

The routes created with the default reagent template look like this:

```
;; -------------------------
;; Routes

(def router
  (reitit/router
   [["/" :index]
    ["/items"
     ["" :items]
     ["/:item-id" :item]]
    ["/about" :about]]))
```

If I change the path of one ("/about" to "/test" below), why does it no longer work? There must be something else driving the routing, but I can't seem to figure out what.

```
;; -------------------------
;; Routes

(def router
  (reitit/router
   [["/" :index]
    ["/items"
     ["" :items]
     ["/:item-id" :item]]
    ["/test" :about]]))
```

[image: invalid reponse]

This is the default reagent template (lein new reagent...) and I haven't changed anything else in the code. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Edit - Some additional detail
I poked around in the repl a little bit in this function (from the default template):

```
(defn init! []
  (clerk/initialize!)
  (accountant/configure-navigation!
   {:nav-handler
    (fn [path]
      (let [match (reitit/match-by-path router path)
            current-page (:name (:data  match))
            route-params (:path-params match)]
        (reagent/after-render clerk/after-render!)
        (session/put! :route {:current-page (page-for current-page)
                              :route-params route-params})
        (clerk/navigate-page! path)
        ))
    :path-exists?
    (fn [path]
      (boolean (reitit/match-by-path router path)))})
  (accountant/dispatch-current!)
  (mount-root))
```

Everything looks ok to me. In fact, executing the below steps in the repl successfully navigated the browser to the correct page. I still can't enter the URL directly though.

```
app:problem.core=> (require '[reitit.frontend :as reitit])
nil
app:problem.core=> (reitit/match-by-path router "/test")
{:template "/test",
 :data {:name :about},
 :result nil,
 :path-params {},
 :path "/test",
 :query-params {},
 :parameters {:path {}, :query {}}}
app:problem.core=> (def match (reitit/match-by-path router "/test"))
#'problem.core/match
app:problem.core=> (:name (:data match))
:about
app:problem.core=> (:path-params match)
{}
app:problem.core=> (def current-page (:name (:data match)))
#'problem.core/current-page
app:problem.core=> (page-for current-page)
#'problem.core/about-page
app:problem.core=> (session/put! :route {:current-page (page-for current-page) :route-params {}})
{:route {:current-page #'problem.core/about-page, :route-params {}}}
app:problem.core=>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you changed the routes on client-side, in `src/cljs/<project_name>/core.cljs`, but did not change them server side in `src/clj/<project_name>/handler.clj` (look under the `def app` near the bottom of the file).

If your new to developing web applications with Clojure, I'd recommend looking at [Luminus](https://luminusweb.com/), rather than using the Reagent template. It's a much more batteries included-approach, with a lot more documentation. The book "Web Development With Clojure" is written by the same author (who is also a contributor to Reagent), and is also recommended reading.